# C# MVVM Select row and run command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have this kind of problem.
I normally select row in datagrid by left or right mouse click.
But I need on right click run command.
I use this code

`<DataGrid.InputBindings>
<MouseBinding Command="{Binding ShowDWClickOnRightButton}" MouseAction="RightClick" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>`

But this not working, because in command parameter I have null (no selected Item). Can you please give me some advice how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: I have written a behavior, which select item on right click. It is for a TreeView, but I think you can adjust it for a GridView. Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43118460/7713750

Comment: I try check you solution ... i need select and run command with selected row. So hope it will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `SelectedItem` because it is not set when right mouse button is clicked.

1. You can either set [selectedItem before right mouse button is pressed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/63fa1e10-1050-4448-a2bc-62dfe0836f25/selecting-datagrid-row-when-right-mouse-button-is-pressed?forum=wpf)
2. Call some method from your ViewModel directly from codebehind with appropriate row object:
   wpf:

   `< DataGrid Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="myDataGrid"  MouseRightButtonDown="myDataGrid_MouseRightButtonDown" ...`

codebehind:

```
private void myDataGrid_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource == null) return;
            var row = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement((DataGrid)sender, e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as DataGridRow;

            if (row != null)
            {
                (this.DataContext as ViewModel).SomeViewModelMethod(row.DataContext as YourRowClass);
            }
        }
```

3. Set Command in `ItemTemplate` like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14026300/5151500)

Comment: I try check, but looking for solution with no code behind.